# Discord.js It is necessary to have the message sent to Embed (so it could be the specified parameters

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

It is necessary to have the message sent to Embed (so it could be the specified parameters (color, author, title, description, addField, content message)
Example: https://embedbuilder.nadekobot.me/

```
const arg = message.content.slice().trim().split(/ +/g);

let name = arg[1];
if (!name) return message.channel.send(channelEmbed);
let anonce = args.slice(1).join();
if(!anonce) return message.channel.send(anonceEmbed);

let anoncechannel = message.guild.channels.find(`name`, name);

anoncechannel.sendEmbed(anonce)
```

Comment: Also `.sendEmbed()` is deprecated. You should only use `.send()`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`RichEmbeds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed).
You can build a new RichEmbed and then send it to the channel you want. You can set every value, title, description, color, footer..
Example:

```js
const exampleEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Some title')
    .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
    .setAuthor('Some name', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png', 'https://discord.js.org')
    .setDescription('Some description here')
    .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
    .addField('Regular field title', 'Some value here')
    .addField('Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)
    .addField('Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)
    .addField('Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)
    .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Some footer text here', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png');

message.channel.send({ embed: exampleEmbed });
```

*source: [discordjs.guide](https://discordjs.guide/#/popular-topics/miscellaneous-examples?id=sending-an-embed)*

This would be the output:
[image]